# How to prove or disprove that $\{ 12x + 25y | x , y \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For phone users,
Prove or disprove that
$\{ 12x + 25y | x , y \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \mathbb{Z}$
I'm not sure if the counterexample of this proof is $12x+25y = 0$ or not.
I'm totally confused, would somebody please help me?

Comment: How is that a counterexample?  $12\times 25+25\times (-12)=0$, not to mention $12\times 0 +25\times 0 =0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$25-2(12)=1$. If $n$ is any integer then we can multiply the equation by $n$ to get $n=25n-(12)(2n)=25y+12x$ where $y=n$ and $x=-2n$. This proves that RHS is contained in LHS. Since the reverse inclusion is obvious  we get the equality.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for the answer for a week!

Answer (score 1):

By Bézout's Theorem, you can write
$$12x + 25y = \gcd(12,25)$$
for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since, $12 = 2^2 3$ and $25 = 5^2$, what is the $\gcd(12,25)$? How do you use it to show that $\mathbb{Z} \subset \{12x + 25y\mid x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$